# Map different arrays into same component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Using react, I need to pass by props data to a component, the only problem is that this data comes from two different arrays.

How can I pass it by creating only one component?

If I do this, mapping both arrays, I get two components and it has to be only one:

```
const Field2 = (props) => {

    return (

        <div className={"field2"}>

            {props.thumbnails.map(a =>
                <Field2Content label={a.label}
                />
            )}

            {props.texturasEscolhidas.map(b =>
                <Field2Content name={b.name}
                />
            )}

        </div>
    )
};

export default Field2;
```

If I do:

```
    {props.thumbnails.map(a =>
        <Field2Content label={a.label}
                       name={'hello'}
        />
    )}
```

I get this:

[image]

The 'hello' is what I need to get from the `texturasEscolhidas` array.

"Color of leg" and "Colour" are created when the component is renderer, the `Hello` should only appear when a button is clicked, and it's dynamic, changing by which of button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use just one component, assuming the both arrays have the same length, you can get the `label` and the `name` by iterating one array and accessing the element of the other array by index (the second parameter in the callback of the `map`):

```
const Field2 = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={"field2"}>
            {props.thumbnails.map((a, index) =>
                <Field2Content
                   label={a.label}
                   name={(props.texturasEscolhidas[index] || {}).name}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Great! While I was trying to understand the question, you posted an answer.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Yes, I supposed the OP referred to code repetition. :) Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău So, how can I then access the name prop ? I need to pass the label from one array and the name from the other

Comment: @IonicăBizău in second array OP are using `name` instead of `label`

Comment: @NelsonSilva I think I misunderstood the question too. Check out the edit. Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What is that? `texturasEscolhidas`

Comment: @BhojendraNepal It's the second array. I assume it means *selected textures* according to Google Translate (from Portuguese).

Comment: @IonicăBizău I get `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. This is like, creating title when the component renders, and then, by clicking on something, I get the text that refers to that title.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal yes as Ionica said, it's the second array passed by props and yes, it means " selected textures" :)

Comment: @NelsonSilva OK, you need to tell us in your question what those arrays contain. The question is unclear to me, still.

Comment: @NelsonSilva Shouldn't the two arrays have the same length?

Comment: @IonicăBizău no, the second one its empty and gets objects with the click on the buttons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169440/discussion-between-ionic-bizu-and-nelson-silva).